# For C#, how to get the hostname by a private IP address on a specific DNS server

Tags: c#, .net, dns

I have tried DnDns and JHSpftware, but they only accept public IP address. The .net Dns can show the private IP hostname, but it doesn't support on selecting a specific DNS server to do that. Can anybody know other solution?

Comment: Why would any given DNS server know a private IP address?

Comment: @itsme86 The DNS server is also internal DNS server. Also IP address

Comment: I still don't think there's enough context to work with here, but if you want a solution, you can always roll your own: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt

Comment: IP addres and DNS server are in your lan segment?

Comment: @mcNets Yes. Basically, I can use (Dns.GetHostEntry(clientIP)).HostName to get it, but I want to specify DNS server.

Comment: @YunfengZhao I suppose Dns.GetHostEntry() or Dns.GetHostName() uses System.NetworkInterface information to send a dns request to GetProperties().DnsAddresses server. (But It is a modest assumption) Maybe you can change this information by code.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution using JHSoftware.DnsClient. Before I am wrong, I should use LookupReverse to get Host Name from an IP. It's working now.